# Is the below error from GenericErrorPage.htm

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis, web-config

Is the below error looks same as from GenericErrorPage.htm?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Runtime Error 
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>


Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page (some times call the [yellow screen of death](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=7&ved=0CBoQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.codinghorror.com%2Fblog%2Farchives%2F000452.html&rct=j&q=yellow+screen+of+death&ei=TMoPS7axAYrflAe1-JmjBA&usg=AFQjCNGDogf4QSAucAdrxpKbfvUo_jHmRw)) gets generated from the ASP.NET Worker process. It is telling you there is an error with your application, but due to the settings in the web.config file, the error has been hidden. The reason it gets hidden is so that general internet users don't get a glimpse of your code. They could potentially use that information to exploit a hole in your application.

To see the real error either follow the instructions you posted or view the page from the machine hosting the site. The error will not be masked when you are viewing it locally.

Comment: i would like to know what is the contents of GenericErrorPage.htm is that the same what i posted above? or different..if different what it is?

Comment: No, that is not GenericErrorPage.htm